# How to include missing NAs to R data.frame of unbalanced panel data set?

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

I have an unbalanced panel data for which I would need to include all the missing observations. E.g. I have something like this:

```
         YEAR    VAR
 FIRM.1  YEAR.1  x.1
 FIRM.1  YEAR.3  x.2
 FIRM.2  YEAR.2  x.3
 FIRM.2  YEAR.3  x.4
```

and I would like to add the missing NA's:

```
         YEAR    VAR
 FIRM.1  YEAR.1  x.1
 FIRM.1  YEAR.2  NA
 FIRM.1  YEAR.3  x.2
 FIRM.2  YEAR.1  NA
 FIRM.2  YEAR.2  x.3
 FIRM.2  YEAR.3  x.4
```

How to do this most conveniently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `expand.grid` and `merge`.

Assuming your data is as follows:

```
mydf <- structure(list(FIRM = c("FIRM.1", "FIRM.1", "FIRM.2", "FIRM.2"),
    YEAR = c("YEAR.1", "YEAR.3", "YEAR.2", "YEAR.3"), VAR = c("x.1", "x.2",
    "x.3", "x.4")), .Names = c("FIRM", "YEAR", "VAR"),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
mydf
#     FIRM   YEAR VAR
# 1 FIRM.1 YEAR.1 x.1
# 2 FIRM.1 YEAR.3 x.2
# 3 FIRM.2 YEAR.2 x.3
# 4 FIRM.2 YEAR.3 x.4
```

Use `expand.grid` to create a "full" set of "FIRM" and "YEAR" data, then `merge`.

```
merge(mydf, expand.grid(FIRM = unique(mydf$FIRM), 
                        YEAR = unique(mydf$YEAR)), 
      all.y = TRUE)
#     FIRM   YEAR  VAR
# 1 FIRM.1 YEAR.1  x.1
# 2 FIRM.1 YEAR.2 <NA>
# 3 FIRM.1 YEAR.3  x.2
# 4 FIRM.2 YEAR.1 <NA>
# 5 FIRM.2 YEAR.2  x.3
# 6 FIRM.2 YEAR.3  x.4
```